# Why SecItemAdd return me -50 (invalid params)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keychain

I want to store in the keychain the value "MyKeyValue" and I do like this :

```
NSData* key = [@"MyKeyValue" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData* tag = [@"com.example.MyKey" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* addquery = @{ (id)kSecValueRef: key,
                            (id)kSecClass: (id)kSecClassKey,
                            (id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag,
                           };
OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)addquery, NULL);
```

but this failed with error -50 (Invalid params)
What i did wrong ?

I would like to store in the keychain a string that can be retrieved if the user uninstall and reinstall my app.

Comment: You might bridge also the `NSData` object: `(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: (__bridge CFDataRef)tag`

Comment: yes i did it but it's didn't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because of `kSecValueRef`, as per Apple's guideline `kSecValueRef` accepts a cryptographic key which can be generated through `SecKeyRef`, Please find below,

```
    NSData* tag = [@"com.example.keys.mykey" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* attributes =
    @{ (id)kSecAttrKeyType:               (id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
       (id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits:         @2048,
       (id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs:
           @{ (id)kSecAttrIsPermanent:    @YES,
              (id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag,
              },
       };
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    SecKeyRef privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes,
                                                 &error);
    SecKeyRef publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey);
    NSDictionary* addquery = @{ (id)kSecValueRef: (__bridge id)publicKey,
                                (id)kSecClass: (id)kSecClassKey,
                                (id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag,
                                };
    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)addquery, NULL);
```

For more info please refer [Storing Keys in the Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain?language=objc)